# After grub.cfg edited, grub2.02 jumps to menu when writing password

Tags: grub2

I edited grub.cfg to add a superuser name and password (unencrypted).

The menu entries marked as --unrestricted work ok, but now entering username and password for editing mode, console mode, or entries marked as --user "" don't work; instead, it jumps back to the menu.

How do I resolve this?